# Order in the list of users who recommended deletion of a post

Tags: discussion, review, deletion, user-interface, low-quality-posts

I "recommended deletion" in a [recent LQ review](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/1506947).  As mine is the 6th one, the concerned post has been deleted.

I observed that the users who "recommended deletion" in the blue box appear in a different order than the one on top.

[image: order of users who recommended deletion]

How are the users arranged in the blue box?  I tried comparing the alphabetical order of their user name and the chronological order of their "recommended deleted", but they didn't match the permutation in the blue box.

Answer (score 8):

In fact, in the blue box, the users are arranged in ascending order of their user ID.  To verify this, one might move the mouse over the link of each user.  That would display a tooltip text showing the URL of the user profile.  The user ID appears in the middle of the URL.

Comment: This would have made a great question for a math.se trivia quiz!!

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC The idea of a trivia quiz is fun, maybe for newbies to the site it will be nice to see the site's features.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon -  Heck, if we gamify it (math.se's _forte_) they might be more likely to pay attention to it than a FAQ or a "Welcome" page.

Comment: Over on [metase], a [user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/622284/spevacus) scienced what happens in the more general case when there can be a mix of "Recommend Deletion" votes and "Delete" votes by trusted users: see [In which order are delete voters shown?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/350142/in-which-order-are-delete-voters-shown/350149#350149) for the full details! :)